# i want my content to be saved in the txt file in my system and then it get copied to the another folder

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on javascipt ,i want the data which is entered by the user in textarea get save in some txt file in my system in some specific folder. can anyone please suggest the solution of this problem in javascript  code or jquery .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This may help: [using html5 javascript to generate and save a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file) Still you can never specify a folder.

Comment: You cannot use javascript to direclty save a particular file. If you want to save the data somewhere, first you need to send that data to the API/middleware and try saving there.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript cannot access file system of user**. So, you cannot store the data entered by user in his system.